# How to do calculations on elements from a sublist in R

Tags: r

my code is as follows:

```
x <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
colnames(x) <- c("z", "m")
n_boot<-4
bs <- list()

for (i in 1:n_boot) {
 bs[[i]] <- x[sample(nrow(x), 10, replace = TRUE), ]
}

bt<-matrix(unlist(bs), ncol = 2*n_boot, byrow = FALSE)
colnames(bt) <- rep(c("z","m"),times=n_boot)
M_to_boot <- bt[,seq(2,8,by=2)]

funct<-function(M_boot_max) {  
   od<-(1/((10*((10^((16-M_boot_max-25)/5))^3)/3)*((max(M_boot_max)-min(M_boot_max))/50)))
}
V_boot<-apply(M_to_boot,2,funct)

rows.combined <- nrow(M_to_boot) 
cols.combined <- ncol(M_to_boot) + ncol(V_boot)
matrix.combined <- matrix(NA, nrow=rows.combined, ncol=cols.combined)
matrix.combined[, seq(1, cols.combined, 2)] <- M_to_boot
matrix.combined[, seq(2, cols.combined, 2)] <- V_boot
colnames(matrix.combined) <- rep(c("M_boot","V_boot"),times=n_boot)

df<-as.data.frame(matrix.combined)
start0 <- seq(1, by = 2, length = ncol(df) / 2)
start <- lapply(start0, function(i, df) df[i:(i+1)], df = df)

tests<-lapply(start, function(xy) split(xy, cut(xy$M_boot,breaks=5)))
```

Now I want to prepare some calculations on values V_boot from a sublists. To be specific I want to for each subsample calculate the sum of V_boot. So, for example I want for a bin M_boot "[[4]]$`(0.811,1.25]`" to have a value of sum(V_boot) for that bin. But I cannot figure out how to get to that each V_boot values.

Please help me.

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you want. you want to apply a function to every list and sublist of `tests`, in this case sum? `f <- function(x) lapply(x, function(x) if (inherits(x, 'list')) f(x) else colSums(x)); lapply(tests, f)` like so?

Comment: It is exactly what I need! Thank you very much!